# STORM:how to name a file when many worker create files concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-storm

sorry for my poor English.
There is a big storm cluster which workers is always creating some file concurrently, the question is that I don't want that filename repeated. 
My boss ask me to create a filename with a format 'timestamp-random-othername',timestamp is a number since 1970-1-1 00:00:00,random is a Five digits from 00000 to 99999. There are about one thousands of workers running...and running on different machines. I am looking for a way that make random number not same when timestamp is identical.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure uniqueness you need to either

- use a shared resource, such as a shared directory, or messaging or data grid.
- make it highly unlikely, e.g. use a UUID.
- give each worker a unique id and use this in the file name.

Comment: in storm, a class of bolts has its unique id, maybe it works, your 3th way, thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use current system milliseconds & random num
like this:
System.currentTimeMillis() + String.format("%05d", random.nextInt(99999))

Comment: While usually random, if you have thousands in the same milli-seconds there will be duplicates.

Comment: the milli-seconds has less opportunity to duplicate
if you truely edit a file in same time you can put a base num in redis
then when a user edit it 
1 you get a num 
2 do incr method 
3 next user will get a never duplicate num